# ADO Recordset - Text Field Returned as Double

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

My recordset object returns a field as a Double data type, even though the data source contains text. Because of this conversion, the recordset object returns a null for that field.

The data source is an Excel worksheet with static data. All records in that field contain text data, but with varying lengths (3-800 characters), and is never blank.

I randomly noticed that when I insert an empty column to the right of this field, the SQL query correctly recognizes the field as a text field (more specifically, an adLongVarWChar/Memo field). It's extremely bizzare, but I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what's going on, and if there's a better solution.

I'm using the following connection string with Microsoft Excel 2016:

```
strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & mstrFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
```

Comment: Ae there any formats on the cells? What is some example text?

Comment: A bit more code - including the actual SQL - would be useful

Comment: The connection string is utterly useless here, but the driver will have a hard time interpreting the data types out of the spreadsheet if your data contains multiple, possibly conflicting data types. Verify your data, especially the first few hundreds of records. If **one single record** contains a non-numeric value, the driver will deem it a text column.

Comment: Yep, this is a known issue that even `IMEX = 1` won't solve. The only two workarounds I've had success with are either 1) to put some dummy text data above your actual data rows (so that the 'best guess' data type is fooled into thinking 'Text'), or 2) to read your data via ADO one cell at a time (not exactly a time-efficient method!),